# Gst RTSP server programming

Tags: rtsp, gstreamer

I've installed `gst-rtsp-server` and I wanted to try a simple code. But on compilation I'm getting the following error:

```
In function `main':
test-launch01.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_new'
test-launch01.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_get_media_mapping'
test-launch01.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_new'
test-launch01.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared'
test-launch01.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch'
test-launch01.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_mapping_add_factory'
test-launch01.c:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_attach'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've included the two headers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

add gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0 to pkg-config.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have not linked to the lib. "Undefined reference" usually means that you have included the necessary header files but that the linker has not found the definitions.

Try adding:

```
`pkg-config gstreamer-rtsp-0.10 --libs`
```

to your linker invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was using the below command to compile when I also got similar errors

```
gcc -Wall test-server.c -o test-server $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0)
```

After reading comments above, it looked like not linking to `gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0` lib was the issue so I changed the command as below

```
gcc -Wall test-server.c -o test-server $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0)
```

NOTE: My build environment is Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

After running

```
apt-get install libgstrtspserver-0.10-dev
```

the command

```
pkg-config --libs gstreamer-rtsp-0.10
```

returns

```
-pthread -lgstrtsp-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgstsdp-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lxml2 -lglib-2.0
```

But

```
ls /usr/lib/libgstrtsp*
```

returns

```
/usr/lib/libgstrtspserver-0.10.so
/usr/lib/libgstrtspserver-0.10.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libgstrtspserver-0.10.so.0
```

So, replacing the flag *-lgstrtsp-0.10* by *-lgstrtspserver-0.10* solved this issue for me.