# Gstreamer rtsp server linking in Qt Creator

Tags: c, qt, rtsp, gstreamer

I've installed Gstreamer sdk and trying to compile this code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstRTSPServer *server;
  GstRTSPMediaMapping *mapping;
  GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
  server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();
  mapping = gst_rtsp_server_get_media_mapping (server);
  factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,
        "( videotestsrc is-live=1 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay )");

  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared (factory, TRUE);
  gst_rtsp_media_mapping_add_factory (mapping, "/test", factory);
  g_object_unref (mapping);
  gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL);
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  return 0;
}
```

I am having the same error like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143581/gst-rtsp-server-programming),

> In function `main':
>
> test-launch01.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to
>
> `gst_rtsp_server_new' test-launch01.c:(.text+0x74): undefined
>
> reference to `gst_rtsp_server_get_media_mapping'
>
> test-launch01.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to
>
> `gst_rtsp_media_factory_new' test-launch01.c:(.text+0x95): undefined
>
> reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared'
>
> test-launch01.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to
>
> `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch' test-launch01.c:(.text+0xc9):
>
> undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_mapping_add_factory'
>
> test-launch01.c:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to
>
> `gst_rtsp_server_attach' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am using Qt Creator and here is my .pro file:

> QT       += core
>
> QT       -= gui
>
> TARGET = gstreamer CONFIG   += console CONFIG   -= app_bundle
>
> CONFIG+=link_pkgconfig
>
> PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-0.10
>
> TEMPLATE = app
>
> SOURCES += main.cpp
>
> INCLUDEPATH +=
>   /home/kato/ew-gst-sdk-linux-x86_64-2012.03-0/include/gstreamer-0.10
>
> INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/glib-2.0 INCLUDEPATH +=
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include INCLUDEPATH +=
>   /usr/include/libxml2
>
> LIBS += -L/home/kato/ew-gst-sdk-linux-x86_64-2012.03-0/lib \
>   -lgstreamer-0.10 \
>   -lgstrtsp-0.10

Am linking to ***`pkg-config gstreamer-rtsp-0.10 --libs`***  correctly ??

I got the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My .pro file is :

```
    QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Gestion_Flux_Video
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    streaming.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    streaming.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/gstreamer-sdk/include \
        /opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/gstreamer-0.10 \
        /opt/gstreamer-sdk/lib/glib-2.0/include \
        /opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/glib-2.0 \
        /opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/libxml2

LIBS += -L/opt/gstreamer-sdk/lib -lglib-2.0 \
                                -lgstreamer-0.10 \
                                -lgobject-2.0 \
                                -lgtk-x11-2.0 \
                                -lgstrtsp-0.10 \
                                -lgstapp-0.10 \
        -L/opt/gstreamer-sdk/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/rtsp-server -lgstrtspserver-0.10
```

And the compilation works fine for me.

Comment: So you are able to view your video stream locally or have you set up for remote as well?