# GStreamer - Compiling with RTSP Server

Tags: c, gcc, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to compile a gstreamer program with rtsp-server. I've included the necessary header files and get this error after trying to compile it.

```
In function `main':
stream.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_new'
stream.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points'
stream.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_new'
stream.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch'
stream.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared'
stream.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory'
stream.c:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_attach'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried compiling the program a few different ways based on:

[Gst RTSP server programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143581/gst-rtsp-server-programming)

[Gstreamer rtsp server linking in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904246/gstreamer-rtsp-server-linking-in-qt-creator?rq=1)

The exact `gcc` commands I've used are:

```
gcc stream.c -o stream `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-rtsp-1.0 gstreamer-1.0`
```

and

```
gcc `pkg-config gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-rtsp-1.0 --cflags` stream.c -o stream `pkg-config gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-rtsp-1.0 --libs`
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, apprently I was using pkg-config the wrong way. The new `gcc` command I used is:

```
 gcc stream.c -o stream $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0 gstreamer-1.0)
```